# Update state hooks inside map

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to update a state hook inside a map. Here is the example:

```
const App = () => {
  const [total, setTotal] = useState(); // I want to use it but I receive an error
  const [sampleMap, setSampleMap] = useState([
    { id: 1, name: "John", income: 100 },
    { id: 2, name: "George", income: 200 }
  ]);

  let netIncome = 0;
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>I want to update this after iterating over the map:<b>{netIncome}</b></div>
      {sampleMap.map((value, key) => {
        netIncome += value.income;
        //setTotal(netIncome);
        return (
          <div key={key}>
            {value.name}
            {" - "}
            {value.income}
          </div>
        );
      })}
      <div>net income:{netIncome}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

I want to calculate the total income and propagate it elsewhere. If I use a state hook inside the map, I receive the following error:

```
Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.
```

How can I make this happen?

Comment: Every time you render the component you update the total state once for every item in the sampleMap, causing a re-render, which means you update the total state once for every item in the sample, causing a re-render, which means... Why not just do e.g. `sampleMap.reduce((total, { income }) => total + income, 0)`?

Comment: I asked out of curiosity. I wanted to see if I can run the loop once. I don't know why I received downvotes!

Answer (score 2):

I'd calculate the value in standalone statements *before* returning the JSX:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [sampleMap, setSampleMap] = React.useState([
    { id: 1, name: "John", income: 100 },
    { id: 2, name: "George", income: 200 }
  ]);

  const netIncome = sampleMap.reduce((a, b) => a + b.income, 0);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>I want to update this after iterating over the map:<b>{netIncome}</b></div>
      {sampleMap.map((value, key) => (
          <div key={key}>
            {value.name}
            {" - "}
            {value.income}
          </div> 
      ))}
      <div>net income:{netIncome}</div>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class="react"></div>
```