# React hooks component not updating after map, but see data loading / refreshing with error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router, react-typescript

I'm using React hooks and Typescript.

Basically, I'm grabbing data from an API through a service in useEffect, setting state through a .then(). When I log the data from this point, I can see it in the console, but the component is not updating. I'm an experienced dev but new to React completely.

Also, if I do something dumb like put `{newsItems}` in the return unwrapped  once the data is loaded is will show an error. I'm guessing it is some simple mistake I am just blind to.

Here is the code:

```
import React, { Fragment, useContext, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { IFeedItem, IOwlerResponse, OwlerResponse } from '../../../../app/ models/owler'
import FeedItem from './FeedItem';



function formatOwlerResponse(response: any): OwlerResponse { 
    // console.log(response.feeds);
    return { feeds: response.feeds, pagination_id: response.pagination_Id }

}



class ItemService { 

    getItems(url: string): Promise<OwlerResponse> {
        return fetch(
            `https://api.owler.com/v1/feed/url?domain=${url}&format=json&limit=100`,
            {
              method: "GET",
              headers: new Headers({
                   (Redacted)

              })
            })
            .then(res => res.json())
           // .then(res => res.map((response: any) => formatOwlerResponse(response))
            .then(res => formatOwlerResponse(res))
          
            }} 




export const CompanyNewsFeed = () => {
    
    const [url, setUrl] = useState('google.com');
    const [newsItems , setNewsItems] = useState<IFeedItem[]>([])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true); 
    const client = new ItemService()

    
    
    
    useEffect(()=>{
        client.getItems('google.com').then(r=> {
            console.log(r.feeds)
            setNewsItems(r.feeds); 
        })
        console.log('set')


    }, [url, formatOwlerResponse]);



    return (
        <Fragment>
                        
                 {newsItems.map(item =>{
                     <Fragment key={item.id}>
                        <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                        <p>{item.description}</p>

                     </Fragment>


                 })} 

        </Fragment>
            


        
       

    )
}

export default CompanyNewsFeed
```

Update -> I made a button for forceUpdate() and refresh() when I hit those I got an error that said I might have more than one version of react installed, which would account for the odd behaviour, since I've seen tutorials mostly mapped out exactly like my application. I did have a moment where I was changing the dependences to take care of warnings and I was at various points on 16.8, 16.14, and 17.0.1 or 17.1. I had had Mobx in too, and I spent a day checking that that was setup correctly. Will update if that doesn't solve it.

Comment: not adding a key in your map may be a cause for react update prevention

Comment: like <Fragment key={item.id}> right under map(?

Comment: More info about map and key: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64268908/update-state-hooks-inside-map and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60710716/how-to-use-map-function-for-hooks-usestate-properties-dynamically and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63064061/reactjs-hooks-update-value-of-map

Comment: what's the error that you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting an error, its just not updating. In the title, I'm saying if I force an error once it loads, the error shows, so its refreshing but the html is not updating (?). Thanks @jqueryHtmlCSS, I'll check those out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the mistake here was actually none of the above. Showed this to a friend of mine in an interactive sandbox, within 10 minutes he saw that this:

```
             {newsItems.map(item =>{
                 <Fragment key={item.id}>
                    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                    <p>{item.description}</p>

                 </Fragment>


             })}
```

Should be

```
             {newsItems.map(item =>(
                 <Fragment key={item.id}>
                    <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                    <p>{item.description}</p>

                 </Fragment>


             ))}
```

Can't believe I didn't see it.

Answer (score 1):

Just need to consider these

first you're adding `[url, formatOwlerResponse]` as `useEffect` dependency array so if none of the `variables` don't change so your `api` will only be called `once`.

another thing that you need to consider is that to check for `newsItems` length because your `mapping` through it and if it's not an array it would give you an error

```
return (
      <Fragment>
          { newsItems?.map(item =>{
              <Fragment key={item.id}>
                <h1>{item.title}</h1>
                <p>{item.description}</p>
              </Fragment>
          })} 
      </Fragment>
  )
```

Comment: thanks because of typescript #2 is less of a concern since we are enforcing types, i did check and make sure, and it is always an array, either 0 or 100 in length. #1 i think is the problem. Those dependencies were a holdover, but I think basically useEffect update is causing this issue, I need to rework my use of useEffect. Idk if that will solve the problem but it might.